# Bash script for looping through files

Tags: bash

I have several files in a folder, e.g. in \home\ directory. Now I want a bash script which loops through all the files and executes a command for each file (the command uses the file name).

How can I do this?

Comment: In future @Thomas, there's an independent [Unix and Linux se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), that might have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you get started:

```
for file in /home/directory/*; do
filename=${file##*/}
echo "$filename"
##execute command here with $filename
done
```

If there are folders too in that directory then you will need to check for files:

add this line immediately after `for..do`:

```
[[ ! -f $file ]] && continue
```

If you want to ignore symbolic links, then:

```
[[ ! -f $file || -L $file ]] && continue
```

---

Additional (according to comment):

You can check if a string (mask) is in the file name or not with:

```
if [[ $filename == *mask* ]];then
echo it's there
else
echo It's not there
fi
```

You can modify the filename like this:

```
#assuming you want to add mask before the extension
newfilename="${filename%%.*}_mask${filename#*.}"
echo "$newfilename"
```

`${filename%%.*}` is the part of `$filename` without extension

`${filename#*.}` is the extension of `$filename`

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I select only certain files? For example, only selecting files without "mask" in their filename, e.g. test-file.zip. Additionally in each loop iteration I want do declare a variable with a "mask" added, i.e. test-file-mask.zip. How can I do this?

Comment: @Thomas, I have added some example code to do what you need (I suppose), If I am missing anything let me know. N.B: `$newfilename` is the variable which contains the value `test-file_mask.zip`

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *;
do
    echo $file
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. With `xargs`

`xargs` is useful for take a list from `stdin` and use each of them with a command, example:

```
    ls yourdir/ | xargs yourcmd
```

2. With a `for` loop

Loop can be use with a list of words or with a wildcard, example:

```
    for i in *; do yourcmd $i ; done
    # for i in `ls youdir`; do yourcmd $i ; done # Never do that
```

3. With `find`

`find` allow to do it in one command, example (from [GNU find man](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find)):

```
find . -type f -exec file '{}' \;
```

> Runs  'file'  on   every file in or below the current directory.  Notice
>     that the braces are enclosed in single quote marks to protect them from
>     interpretation  as  shell  script punctuation.    The semicolon is simi-
>     larly protected by the use of a backslash, though ';' could  have  been
>     used in that case also.

Comment: Oh.. NO, NO, NO see: [**why for i in ls... is always wrong**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate only over files, then:

```
find <your-dir> -type f | xargs <your-cmd>
```

For example if you wanted to change access rights of only files in a current directory (but leave all the directories untouched):

```
find . -type f | xargs -n 1 chmod  u+rw
```

The `-n 1` part tells `xargs` to invoke `chmod` for each directory separately (which is not the most efficient in this case, but you should get the idea).